# Access non-hash value in hash Ruby - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, file-upload, hash

i have the following:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"b3+vGGBgjaxZ5W7UhJIZfqK9vz7MsAi1ipeDrDV1vgo=", "commit"=>"Upload", "remotipart_submitted"=>"true", "X-Requested-With"=>"IFrame", "X-Http-Accept"=>"text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01", "uploaded_file"=>{"uploaded_file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb5f72ac8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140306-2294-1ifwfm5>, @original_filename="INSTRUCTION.txt", @content_type="text/plain", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file[uploaded_file]\"; filename=\"INSTRUCTION.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n">}}
```

So here if i want to access the parameter "uploaded_file" i will go:

```
params[:uploaded_file]
```

And if i want to get the uploaded_file value inside i will do:

```
(params[:uploaded_file])["uploaded_file"]
```

Which will return:

```
<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb5f72ac8
```

**But I am wondering, how am i supposed to access the @headers inside this uploaded_file hash?**

Thanks in advice! (:

PS: If anyone knows what

`<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb5f72ac8`

means and if it can be useful for something it will be awesome. {:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb5f72ac8` refers to an instance of `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` class

To access @headers use

```
params[:uploaded_file][:uploaded_file].headers
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a ton, but can you explain why is it [:uploaded_file].headers, you mean all of the variables after the first key "uploaded_file" are its childs?

Comment: `params[:uploaded_file][:uploaded_file]` returns an object of `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` class. `headers` is an attribute/property defined in the class.

Comment: Awhh, i see now, it looks silly that i did not think of that earlier when i look it right now, thanks you {: And about that, can i use this file in some way, like read it or save it?

Comment: Glad to help. Refer to UploadedFile documentation at:  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html

Comment: really appreciate your help <3
P.S. A small reward: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYeTEw_jHlo